# user session confusion in symfony 2

Tags: php, session, symfony

How can I handle user session in symfony? because I'm reading the book of symfony 2 and it says:

> Storing and retrieving information from the session can be easily achieved from any controller:

```
$session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
// store an attribute for reuse during a later user request
$session->set('foo', 'bar');
// in another controller for another request
$foo = $session->get('foo');
// use a default value if the key doesn't exist
$filters = $session->get('filters', array());
```

I wonder how to destroy the session. I'm a newbie in symfony so please explain. I'm confused because I found a thread that says its not the way to handle user sessions in symfony2  http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=42766

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you pointed to is how it used to be until `Symfony 2.2` (I think) - that is, it is outdated. Which exact version do you have installed?

You create session by:

```
$session = new Session();
```

If you want to invalidate whole session:

```
$session->invalidate();
```

of just single value:

```
$session->remove('some_key');
```

You can find complete API of `Session` [**here**](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/SessionInterface.html#method_remove).

Comment: Symfony version 2.4.0 - app/dev/debug. oh thats why.. what about the code that i post? what version is it applicable?

Comment: Other than mentioned creation of Session object, I think that it all should work fine...